# Prepared statements in MySQLi

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm doing SQL queries in prepared statements(MySQLi)

This is the query

```
$register = $friend_zone->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, username, password, email, security_answer, date, user_level, security_question) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$register->bind_param($name, $username, $password, $email, $security_answer, $date, $user_level, $security_question);

$register->execute();
```

Im getting a warning

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /var/www/includes/functions.php on line 152 Notice: Undefined variable: result in /var/www/includes/functions.php on line 159
```

Can someone help?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php The manual is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function wrong. The first parameter is a string containing the data types. For example:

```
$register->bind_param('ssssssis', $name, $username, $password, $email, $security_answer, $date, $user_level, $security_question);
```

Each letter corresponds to it's respective variable. `s` is for strings and `i` is for integers. There are some other ones available too.

Comment: so 'ssssssis' refers to the type of the variables like $name, $username
Is my hunch corrrect?

Comment: Exactly. I believe it is a *type hinting* feature added to help prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$register = $friend_zone->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, username, password, email, security_answer, date, user_level, security_question) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$register->execute( array($name, $username, $password, $email, $security_answer, $date, $user_level, $security_question) );
```